# Faces and shared album

Tags: photos

My wife and I share all the pictures of our family in an iCloud shared album.
I then have several smart albums which include different members of the family.

The problem is that there is no faces metadata in the shared album and I only find photos in my own library.

- Is there a way to add faces to photos in a shared album?
- Is there a way to import all the shared photos that my wife publishes in my library? (I tried to create a smart album which includes all the photos in the shared album and not photos in my library, but the only albums that I can choose are my own)

Any other idea?